# Azure Storage Connection Error (if system time difference)

Tags: c#, azure

I connect to blob azure storage on windows phone 8.1. If the request date ~ system time, it works fine. But if the system date on phone have a difference... e.g. 1 day... then it have error always...

```
public static async Task<AzureDownloadResult> DownloadFileFromBlob(string FileName)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        try
        {
            CloudBlobContainer container = GetBlobClient.GetContainerReference("data");
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(FileName);
            if (!await blockBlob.ExistsAsync())
            {
                return new AzureDownloadResult(null, AzureDownloadException.NotExists);
            }
            long filesize = blockBlob.Properties.Length;
            await blockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(ms.AsOutputStream());
            if (ms.Length != filesize)
            {
                return new AzureDownloadResult(null, AzureDownloadException.Error);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //<-error there (if i set random time in phone time settings):
            //message: ...Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature..
            return new AzureDownloadResult(null, AzureDownloadException.NoneInternetConnectionOrDateTimeError);
        }
        return new AzureDownloadResult(ms.ToArray(), AzureDownloadException.OK);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Azure Storage REST API, upon which all other libraries are built, uses the date as one of the request parameters providing entropy when creating the HMAC authentication token for the request. The following is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179428.aspx):

> The storage services ensure that a request is no older than 15 minutes
>   by the time it reaches the service. This guards against certain
>   security attacks, including replay attacks. When this check fails, the
>   server returns response code 403 (Forbidden).

Consequently, you should ensure that the datetime associated with the request is within that 15 minute window.

Comment: It would be nice if I could manually set the date of the request, otherwise I must to give the user a message that date and time settings are incorrect... I will try to use other authentication methods... thank for the link!

Comment: So you'd prefer to make your solution less secure? Seems weird. Timeouts are a fact of life on long running requests on high latency connections. Your app should deal with this situation appropriately.